# Biology tag management, merging, and cleanup (2015)

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

In light of AliceD's question [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/how-to-remove-or-substitute-a-tag), I decided to start a tag: management, merging, and cleanup post. The idea is being borrowed from math.SE.

---

The rules of the game are:

- post your suggestion as an answer here if use see

  - a particularly bad tag (rule of thumb: «roughly speaking ... if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it»),
  - a tag that should be a synonym of an existing one,
  - a tag that used for two or more completely unrelated things;
- upvote/downvote/comment as your agree/disagree with suggestions;
- wait a day or two before implementing suggestion;
- when retagging questions by hand please keep your rate down to a few posts a day, so not to flood the main page.

---

The rules were borrowed from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014). Also, the linked thread will give everyone and opportunity to see how it works.